# Actionscript 3 scaling

Tags: actionscript-3, scale

I've recently started coding in Actionscript 3, and I've run into a problem when trying to scale a MovieClip.

```
{
    private var valGrandX:Number;
    private var valGrandY:Number;
    public function Bonhomme_Fil()
    {
        valGrandX = this.scaleX;
        valGrandY = this.scaleY;

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, big);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, small);
    }
    private function big(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.scaleX *=  1.5;
        this.scaleY *=  1.5;
    }
    private function small(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        this.scaleX = valGrandX;
        this.scaleY = valGrandY;
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the Clip become larger when the user's mouse hovers over it, and return to its normal size when he hovers outside of it. What ends up happening is that when it scales to a bigger size it moves towards the bottom and right, and ends up flickering back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

When you design a MovieClip, there is its center marked with small (+). This point is (0,0) of the MovieClip itself and (x,y) of the MovieClip in its parent coordinates. When you scale/rotate this MovieClip with AS3 commands, it scales/rotates around this point. You need to redesign the content of the MovieClip so it is placed equally around its (0,0), then you'll have the effect of "zooming in place".

Also you might want to add a transparent button (with 4th frame - it's its hit area - only) if your MovieClip has "holes" or content inconsistencies for the mouse to fall through.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_OVER) and [`MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_OUT).

Check [what is the difference between roll over and mouse over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075842/what-is-the-difference-between-roll-over-and-mouse-over)

Or set code like this:

```
private var valGrandX:Number;
private var valGrandY:Number;
public function Bonhomme_Fil()
{
    valGrandX = this.scaleX;
    valGrandY = this.scaleY;

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, big);
}
private function big(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //this.scaleX *=  1.5;
    //this.scaleY *=  1.5;
    this.scaleX =  1.5;
    this.scaleY =  1.5;

    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, big);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, small);
}
private function small(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.scaleX = valGrandX;
    this.scaleY = valGrandY;

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, big);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, small);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it didn't work. It seems that for some reason the x and y coordinates are changing in addition to the scale starting from the top left cordner.

Comment: See edited answer. Then your problem is `this.scaleY *=  1.5` Remove multiplier character.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that the x,y value is not changed , please try to refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574943/scaling-from-the-center-in-flash)

Comment: Hi, I've tried that but it seems that for some reason the values of x and y are changing even though it's not in the AS script...